# How to call a function with ethereum alarm clock?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, scheduling

In Ethereum alarm clock who is calling the contract (scheduler?) that executes the function programmed in my contract. I mean, I have a function in my contract that needs to run on a certain date, but who calls this function when the time comes? Which node? I don't understand if the timenode is the same as my node (geth / parity) or is it another ndo?

Answer (score 1):

They have a video how to setup a time node https://blog.chronologic.network/how-to-prove-day-ownership-to-be-a-timenode-3dc1333c74ef.

A timenode is a separate application from regular ethereum clients (geth, parity, besu, etc).

A timenode is configured with an account that will be used to send transactions.